# Python List of Tuples (Find value with key + check if exist)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples wich is:

```
TupleList = [("computer", "weird working machine"),("phone","talkerino"),("floor", "walk on")]
```

And what i want to do is get the value printed out if i have the key

Like:

```
x = raw_input("Word to lookup: ") # I insert "computer"
```

and it should print out "weird working machine"

TD LR: Get the Value with the Key

Another thing i need to fix is that if i try to append the Tuple with a new word that ALREADY exists in the tuple it should print "Already exists" else it should append with the new word. Something like this:

```
if(word in tuple exist)
    print "Already exist"
else
    TupleOrd.append(((raw_input("\n Word to insert: ").lower()),(raw_input("\n Description of word: ").lower())))
```

Comment: You should use a dictionary for key-value pairs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tuples aren't the greatest data type for key-value lookup. Consider using a dictionary instead:

```
>>> TupleList = [("computer", "weird working machine"),("phone","talkerino"),("floor", "walk on")]
>>> d = dict(TupleList)
>>> d["computer"]
'weird working machine'
```

It also makes it easier to check for the presence of existing words:

```
key = raw_input("Word to insert:").lower()
if key in d:
    print "Sorry, that word is already present"
else:
    d[key] = raw_input("Description of word:").lower()
```

---

If you absolutely must use a tuple, you can search for keys with a loop:

```
for key, value in TupleList:
    if key == "computer":
        print value
```

and similarly determine which keys already exist:

```
key_exists = False
for key, value in TupleList:
    if key == "computer":
        key_exists = True
if key_exists:
    print "Sorry, that word is already present"
else:
    #todo: add key-value pair to tuple
```

Comment: I'm not so sure i'm allowed to make it into a dictionary since the "Mission" is to make it with 1. lists 2. tuples 3. dictionary :D But i can use it until then :D Maybe hard to do it without dict But ty! :)

Comment: Like is there any way to find it with a for-loop and if? (Without dictionary)

Comment: Yeah, but it's not as easy. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

One **crazy** way to do this would be:

```
TupleList = [("computer", "weird working machine"),("phone","talkerino"),("floor", "walk on")]
x = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
key_exists = next(iter([i[1] for i in TupleList if i[0] == x]), None)) is not None
if key_exists:
    print 'key exists'
```

Comment: This reimplements a dict lookup. On large Lists of Tuples it will be slow as it requires cycling through each Tuple for matches whereas Dicts are backed by a hash table.